# Find the remainder of $7^{2002}$ divided by 101.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is what I have so far:
Since 101 is a prime and does not divide 7, we can apply Fermat's Little Theorem to see that $$7^{100} \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 101)$$
We can then reduce $7^{2002}$ to $7^{2} (7^{100})^{20} \equiv 7^{2}(1)^{20} \ (mod \ 101)$ which is where I'm stuck at.
$7^2=49 \equiv 150 \ (mod \ 101)$. How do I reduce $7^2$ in a way that is constructive towards my solution since $(mod \ 101)$ is such a large modulus to operate in?

Comment: $7^2 \pmod{101} \equiv 49\pmod{101}$  You did the hard part... :)

Comment: 49 is already as reduced as it's going to get.

Comment: Don't you already have the answer ($7^2 \equiv 49 (\mod 101)$)?

Comment: $49$ is enough for the answer. You won't need $150$.

Comment: I can have 49 as a remainder? I find that hard to visualize

Comment: When you divide by $101$, your remainder should be some non-negative integer less than $101$.  $49$ is fine.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the solution and broke it :)

At

$$7^{2002}  \equiv 49\pmod {101} \,,$$

you are done, the remainder must be $49$. Indeed, if you denote the remainder by $r$ then $0 \leq r \leq 100$ and

$$ r \equiv 49 \pmod{101} \,.$$

This means that $101|r-49$, and since $-49 \leq r-49 < 52$ you get $r-49=0$.